# How do I get URL with a setup of EC2 Windows Server and XAMPP to host PHP Server?

Tags: php, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am going through [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-stripe-payment-integration/) and because I am using `stripe`, I cannot connect to `http://localhost/donate/payments.php` because it is not `https`, and `stripe/iOS` requires this.

So I set up an `AWS Windows Server`, downloaded and installed `Xampp`, and now trying to connect to my server from my App.

The problem is, if I run `ifconfig` and try to `ping` the `ip_addr` given, I get a `timeout`. I opened up port `80` and `443` and I'm still getting this problem.

Where do I find the correct `URL` to ping to ensure that my App can connect to the server?

I'm sure I'm missing some crucial information and maybe a lot, so if you have any reference articles for me to read that would be very helpful as well.

Any suggestions?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I would start with checking that you can telnet to port 80 from the same machine. if you can telnet the next thing you should figure is what is the public ip. assuming you are not using an elastic loadbalancer please read the following post http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html this will help you figure how to setup an elastic ip to your ec2 instance, here is another simple youtube I've found for it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3F2vIQYlu8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the EC2 console select the instance and look in the Description tab. You can use either the Public DNS or the Public IP to access your instance. I believe `ifconfig` will report the Private IP, which won't be accessible outside your AWS VPC.

Also, at some point you will want to look into assigning an Elastic IP to your EC2 instance to prevent the IP address from ever changing.

Comment: So I went to that location and got the public ip. The IP is 52.11.110.XX. I try pinging it, and i still get a timeout. I even tried removing the windows firewall for a minute and tried again, still to no avail. My assumption is that if I can't ping it, then there is no way I would get AFNetworking request through to my php server. Is this correct? Is there anything else I should try?

Comment: I will add that I can remote desktop into the instance

Comment: Your assumption about ping is incorrect. Ping works on a different protocol, and is blocked by default on AWS. Anyway, I answered your question about obtaining the URL. Now to open your server to inbound traffic you need to open the port(s) in both the Windows firewall and the EC2 security group.